# CSS Transistions being called on scrollTop function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I have a couple of div's I'd like to either scale down on move the padding up using Javascript and jQuery and this does work....except it doesn't perform the transition:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){

    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 200)
    {
        jQuery('.site-title').css("width", "80px", "height", "80px");
        jQuery('.main-navigation').css("padding", "2.25rem 0 0 0");
        jQuery('.search-box-wrapper').css("padding", "2.2rem 0 0 0");
    }

    if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() < 200)
    {
       jQuery('.site-title').css("width", "160px", "height", "160px");
       jQuery('.main-navigation').css("padding", "4.55rem 0 0 0");
       jQuery('.search-box-wrapper').css("padding", "4.4rem 0 0 0");
    } 
});
```

So I've added things like 'transition: padding .5s ease-in-out;' to the original styles but no animation / transition takes place. What would be the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: Update: Got the padding taken care of by adding 'transition: padding .5s ease-in-out;' to the actual style in the CSS. So that works but the width and height of the .site-title do not animate even after adding a similar style.

Comment: `css("width", "80px", "height", "80px")` - that's not how you apply multiple values. You need to use an object:  `css({"width": "80px", "height": "80px"})`

Comment: That didn't work. In fact, it made the animation of the padding on the navigational area not function either.